# How to convert image type to 'jpg' using imagemagick in node.js

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I am using imagemagick in my node.js app. I have resized the image as follows:

```
im.resize({
        format: 'jpg',
        srcPath: imagePath,
        dstPath: thumbPath,
        width: 220,
        }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
        //some code
       }
});
```

I want my code to convert the incoming images to `jpg`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The `jimp` npm package (full js) seems to be able to do that pretty well: https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/tree/master/packages/jimp

Answer (score 3):

For this solution you need use [easyimage package](https://github.com/hacksparrow/node-easyimage) . This package run under and need imagemagick (very important).

```
$npm install easyimage --save // saved in your package.json
```

Including in your code:

```
var easyimg = require('easyimage');
```

First you need get the path of original image:

```
tmp_path = 'path/to/image.svg';
```

Now you change the extension of the "tmp_path":

```
tmp_extless = tmp_path.replace('.svg','.png'); //be sure of include "."
```

So, tmp_path is the original path, and tmp_extless is the path of our future image.

Now, the magic of easyimage:

```
easyimg.convert({src: tmp_path, dst: tmp_extless, quality: 80},
    function(err,stdout){ 
      if(stdout){ console.log('stdout', stdout);
        //here you can run a script to delete tmp_path
      }
    }
);
```

Now, your new image is in the path: tmp_extless.
With this method you don't need writeFile or readFile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `writeFileSync` and pipe your data in through the anonymous function.

```
im.resize({
        format: 'jpg',
        srcPath: imagePath,
        dstPath: thumbPath,
        width: 220,
        }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
            fs.writeFileSync('[filename].jpg', stdout,'binary'); //write the file here
       }
});
```

I believe you also need to call the convert method.

```
im.convert(['originalfilename.originalextension', 'jpg:-'],
```

Comment: .convert() works. Apparently there is no need for writeFileSync()(though I would surely like to know the exact use of the same). Thanks for your help.